# How can I clean out bad fuel from my diesel engined VW Transporter?

Tags: fuel-system, vw, fuel-injectors, transporter

How do I clean out bad fuel from my VW transporter TDI, and also clean the injectors.

Can I do this myself?

Edit: Dirty/water fuel not incorrect fuel. It’s dirty...

Comment: by bad fuel, do you mean the wrong fuel (ie petrol rather than diesel) or just fuel that has been in too long and gone bad?

Comment: Dirty/water fuel not incorrect fuel. It’s dirty.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I would suggest that you disconnect the output pipe from the filter and run the pump until clean fuel is pumped through.

Then change the filter for a new clean one. Refit the pipe and bleed as appropriate.

The injectors themselves - if they need cleaning then that is probably a professional job - I have read "stories" of cleaning injectors with shaving foam - but would not consider doing that...

However using a fuel cleaner additive may be an option - if the engine runs fine then just leave it like that...